# check if selected value is 'YES' if so enable a control using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Going crazy here. Working on an asp.net application, need to add some custom validations and just starting to write it and figured I'd test it.

I have a parent control drp1, and 2 child controls txt1 and txt2. On page load, both txt controls are disabled.

when user selects 'Yes' from drp1, I call the below function to try to enable txt1 but it doesn't work and i don't know why :/

```
function EnableDisableSometing() {

    try {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=drp1.ClientID%>").value = "Yes") {
            alert("HERE");
            (document.getElementById("<%=txt1.ClientID%>").disabled = false);

        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("EnableDisableMentalHealthError :" + e.message);
    }
}
```

What happens here is the txt1 gets enabled, however, the selected text value in drop down simply disappears. the second I select 'YES' it enabled txt1 and text in drop down is empty. I can select another value 'NO' for example same thing happens.

All i want to do is check if drp1.text = 'Yes' then enable a bunch of controls, nothing fancy really.

Comment: Change your `=` in the if statement to `==` or `===` :)

Comment: @Xeraqu then it doesn't hit the alert("HERE"); it doesn't seem to think I selected 'Yes'', checked it with == and ===

Comment: I checked it in the console and it comes back with "1", how can I get 'Yes' value with my document.getElementByID from dropDown

Comment: You could always just check that `.value === 1`. To get your dropdown to have specific values on select, we'd need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `=` in your if statement, which is not a boolean operator. It is setting the value of your dropdown to `'Yes'`, not **checking** that it's equal to `'Yes'`.

In order to perform that check, you have to use `==` or `===`, which have a key difference (in JavaScript) that you can read about pretty much anywhere.

Using `==` or `===`, if your `alert` statement is no longer executing, then that means the check failed; ie `document.getElementById("<%=drp1.ClientID%>").value` is not equal to `'Yes'`.

```js
var x = 1;
if (x = 10) // clearly not true, x is 1.
  console.log('Somehow this executes anyway');
  
if (x == 10)
  console.log('This is also going to execute, because we set x to 10 in the above if statement')
  
if (x == 20)
  console.log('This will not execute')
```